# Generalised Birthday Paradox - bins problem

Tags: probability

We are putting balls into bins by the Uniform Distribution. Let $X$ be a random variable and means moment of collision when two balls fall into the same bin. So minimum $X$ is $2$ ($2$ balls in the same bin) and maximum $X$ is $n+1$. What is probability $P(2 \leq X \leq n+1)$ and expected value for $k$ bins and $n$ balls?

Comment: Shouldn't the maximum be $n+1$?

Comment: Possibly yes. I fixed this.

Comment: Should we assume $n > k$?  Otherwise, there is a positive probability of no collisions, and the expected value would be infinite.

Comment: Definition problem "Suppose that balls are placed randomly (one at a time) into n cells. The random placing of balls continues until a ball is placed into a cell that already has one ball (i.e. until a “repeat” occurs). Let X_n be the number of balls required to obtain a repeat."

Comment: I think the maximum should be $k+1$ balls, for $k$ bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \ge 2$, the number of ways to place $x-1$ balls in $n$ bins without repeats, and then produce the first repeat with the next ball, is
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-x+1)!}\cdot (x-1);
$$
dividing this by the total number of ways to place $x$ balls in $n$ bins ($n^{x}$) gives the probability that ball $x$ is the first repeat:
$$
P[X=x]=\frac{n!(x-1)}{(n-x+1)!n^x}=\frac{x-1}{n}\prod_{i=0}^{x-2}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right).
$$
Note that $P[X \ge n+2]=0$, as it must be.  The expected value of $X$ is just
$$
E[X]=\sum_{x}xP[X=x]=\sum_{x=2}^{n+1}\frac{x(x-1)}{n}\prod_{i=0}^{x-2}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right).
$$